# Java Osgi Eclipse JMF javax.media.MediaLocator

Tags: java, osgi, media-player, classnotfoundexception, jmf

i have a problem with OSGI JMF. I wrote this media player but not want to work
when i run got ERROR. Eclipse not see mediaLocator
does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem.
I'm a noob in java.
I have eclipse kepler and JMF2.1.1e, and JDK

```
try {           
        Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(new MediaLocator(mediauUrl));     
        Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();

        Component control = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();...


osgi> 

!SESSION 2014-03-02 18:13:30.610 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=pl_PL
Command-line arguments:  -dev file:C:/OSGI ECLIPSE/ProjektyOSGI/projekt1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/OSGi Framework/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog -console

!ENTRY videoplayer 4 0 2014-03-02 18:13:35.458
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in videoplayer.Activator.start() of bundle videoplayer.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/MediaLocator
    at videoplayer.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:31)
    at videoplayer.ttttt.metoda(ttttt.java:35)
    at videoplayer.Activator.start(Activator.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.MediaLocator cannot be found by videoplayer_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/MediaLocator
    at videoplayer.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:31)
    at videoplayer.ttttt.metoda(ttttt.java:35)
    at videoplayer.Activator.start(Activator.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.MediaLocator cannot be found by videoplayer_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-03-02 18:13:35.470
!MESSAGE Bundle videoplayer_1.0.0.qualifier [50] is not active.
```

Comment: I didn't know that but media player requires codecs.

Comment: I instal codecs. When i was run the project as a java aplication everything is working properly.The program does not work in OSGI Framework

Comment: It's not required to use OSGi, however you can use RCP.

Comment: It is too difficult for me. Thanks for help